# (bootstrap 3)Lost focus when open second window from first

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap for create modal windows in my project. When i create only one window all work fine. If i create second window from first i have a problem.

In First window when i try to scroll it all fine. Window is scrolling. When i open next window from it - scrolling not a current window. Scrolling body behind it.
Example  https://jsfiddle.net/rz4p503n/5/

For create modal window I'm using such function:

```
function createModalWindow(windowid, parentid, template){
    if (parentid.localeCompare('')!=0){
        $(('#' + parentid)).modal('hide');
    }
    $('#' + windowid).detach();
    $("body").append(template);
    $('#' + windowid).modal('show');
}
```

When i create first window body has class 'modal-open'. It removed after create next window.

Why is this happening?

I think lost a focus for scrolling because body hasn't this class.

**UPD**: I tried to modify create/close window function such as:

```
$('body').on('click','.close-and-exit', function () {
    console.log('try to close');
    var windowid =$(this).closest('.modal').attr('id');
    var parentid =$(this).closest('.modal').attr('data-parentid');
    console.log({windowid: windowid, parentid:parentid});
    $('#' + windowid).modal('hide');
    $(('#' + windowid)).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        //$('#' + parentid).modal('show');
        console.log('window: ' + windowid + ' is closed');
        if (typeof parentid!=='undefined'){
            if(parentid.localeCompare('')!=0){
                console.log(' try to show parent window: ' + parentid);
                $('#' + parentid).modal('show');
            }
        }
    })

});
function createModalWindow(windowid, parentid, template){
    console.log('parentid: ' + parentid);
    console.log('windowid: ' + windowid);
    if (parentid.localeCompare('')!=0){
        $(('#' + parentid)).modal('hide');
        $(('#' + parentid)).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            console.log('parent is hided. create new windowЖ');
            $('#' + windowid).detach();
            $("body").append(template);
            $('#' + windowid).modal('show');
        })
    }
    else{
        $('#' + windowid).detach();
        $("body").append(template);
        $('#' + windowid).modal('show');
    }
}
```

Focus not losses. Scrol work only in current window. But a can not close first window after second window. Everytime running

```
$(('#' + parentid)).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {...});
```

from function createModalWindow and it call

```
$('#' + windowid).detach();
$("body").append(template);
$('#' + windowid).modal('show');
```

How I can fix it? I need to scroll and close the window correctly too.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using hidden.bs.modal.
For create function:

```
function createModalWindow(windowid, parentid, template){
    if (parentid.localeCompare('')!=0){
        $(('#' + parentid)).modal('hide');
        $(('#' + parentid)).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            console.log('parent is hided. try to set modal class for body');
            if (($('body').hasClass('modal-open')==false)&& (parentid.localeCompare('')!=0)){
                $('body').addClass('modal-open');
            }
        })
    }
    $('#' + windowid).detach();
    $("body").append(template);
    $('#' + windowid).modal('show');
}
```

For close window:

```
$('body').on('click','.close-and-exit', function () {
    console.log('try to close');
    var windowid =$(this).closest('.modal').attr('id');
    var parentid =$(this).closest('.modal').attr('data-parentid');
    $('#' + windowid).modal('hide');
    $(('#' + windowid)).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        console.log('window: ' + windowid + ' is closed');
        if (($('body').hasClass('modal-open')==false)&& (parentid.localeCompare('')!=0)){
            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        }

    });
    if (typeof parentid!=='undefined'){
        if(parentid.localeCompare('')!=0){
            console.log(' try to show parent window: ' + parentid);
            $('#' + parentid).modal('show');
        }
    }

});
```

For undestand: when the hidden.bs.modal is triggered, I call a check body hasClass 'modal-open' and parentid is not null. Script will add class 'modal-open' to body if body hasn't this class and present parent window